# How not to save user input in database until paypal validates the payment?

Tags: php, session, paypal

I want to get some user info using a html form, After submission, the user input is stored in a session and the user is redirected to paypal to perform payment operation. After the  payment validation, the user will be redirected again to the website and the input will be stored in a database table.

The problem is : session variables are lost after the redirection to the website.

Any one for help?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any reason, why the session should get lost. If the user returns to the same host, his session should be available. How to you create the session?

Comment: i jut use session_start()

Comment: After that, do you emit a new page of your site? If not, the sessionID will not be saved in the user's browser.

Comment: of course, 
the session work fin with the user session, and user can navigate on all user space without loosing session value.

Comment: Based on that statement, I still see no reason, why the session should be gone one the user returns from PayPal.

Comment: i tested my website locally and every thing look fine, however, uploading my website, the probleme still exist

Comment: It seems that the problem have relation with the server configuration. I will work on that.
Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bad idea. Just because the user arrives on the target page doesn't mean they got there after being sent by PayPal. They can even spoof the `Referer` header to make it look like they did.

Instead, save their information BEFORE sending them to PayPal, then use PayPal's IPN system to update it and mark it as paid for.

Answer (score 0):

From the php manual, session_start gets the session id from get, post, or cookie.  It sounds like you're using cookies.  To use cookies for sessions, you need to call session_start before sending anything to the browser.  If this isn't the problem, workaround would be to set the session id as a get parameter and load the session based on that in the return page.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: thank you for your replay, but i have already try this issue.